# Alert Manager SMS Notification

Tags: kubernetes, sms, webhooks, prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

I have a `Prometheus` monitoring running on `Kubernetes` cluster. I want to receive SMS notification when my alerts firing.
How should i set my number for receive SMS in `Alertmanager`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Couple options coming from official docs: https://prometheus.io/docs/alerting/configuration/

Option 1. If you have PagerDuty / VictorOps subscription use https://prometheus.io/docs/alerting/configuration/#pagerduty_config receiver, and setup SMS rule inside the service.

Option 2. Use a webhook receiver https://prometheus.io/docs/alerting/configuration/#webhook_config 
Set it to send notification to AWS SNS https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-http-https-endpoint-as-subscriber.html, then use AWS SNS to send an SMS. Or use any other webhook based SMS sender.

Comment: I highly recommend it cause it's more than SMS router, it also gives you on-call schedules, on-call tiers and so-on

Comment: it doesn't matter, it's the same approach across all types of deployments

Answer (score 1):

The best and most simple option is just to use the [sns_configs](https://prometheus.io/docs/alerting/latest/configuration/#sns_config) in alert-manager, This is my configuration on the prometheus-operator helm-chart in the alert-manager section, Just create an SNS topic give the pod/node permissions to that topic and use the configuration below in the ***values.yaml*** file:

```
alertmanager:
  enabled: true
      config:
        inhibit_rules:
          - source_matchers:
              - 'severity = critical'
            target_matchers:
              - 'severity =~ warning|info'
            equal:
              - 'namespace'
              - 'alertname'
          - source_matchers:
              - 'severity = warning'
            target_matchers:
              - 'severity = info'
            equal:
              - 'namespace'
              - 'alertname'
          - source_matchers:
              - 'alertname = InfoInhibitor'
            target_matchers:
              - 'severity = info'
            equal:
              - 'namespace'
        global:
          resolve_timeout: 5m
          smtp_require_tls: true
          smtp_smarthost: 'email-smtp.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com:587'
          smtp_from: 'alertmanager@bubu.energy'
          smtp_auth_username: 'ZZZZ'
          smtp_auth_password: 'ZZZZ'
          slack_api_url: 'https://hooks.slack.com/services/T02GV75J1HP/B03QN9JL0J0/lXXCX'
        route:
          receiver: 'weev-sns'
          group_by: ['alertname', 'service']
          routes:
            - receiver: 'weev-sns'
              match:
                alertname: 'Watchdog'
              group_wait: '120s'
              group_interval: '1m'
              repeat_interval: '1m'
        receivers:
    
        - name: 'weev-sns'
          sns_configs:
          - sigv4:
              region: 'eu-central-1'
            attributes:
              key: severity
              value: "critical"
            topic_arn: 'arn:aws:sns:eu-central-1:104553556165:alertmanagertopic'
            send_resolved: false
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a GSM modem which is connected to software to send SMS messages. The software accepts GET requests with a simple URL:
`https://sms-server.local/php/sms_gateway.php?key=xxxx&recipients=0151xxxx&message=This+is+an+example`
I created a new receiver in Alertmanager:

```
- name: 'sms-webhook'
  webhook_configs:
  - url: 'http://localhost:8088/'
    max_alerts: 1
```

I wrote a simple Python code to get the POST request from Alertmanager and send it to the SMS server with a GET request:

```py
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer
import requests
from urllib.parse import urlencode

key_data = 'xxxxxx'
recipients_data= '0151xxxxxxx'
target_url = 'https://sms-server.local/php/sms_gateway.php'

class RequestHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):

    def do_POST(self):
        content_length = int(self.headers['Content-Length'])
        post_data = self.rfile.read(content_length)
        post_data_str = post_data.decode('utf-8')

        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header('Content-type', 'text/plain')
        self.end_headers()

        data = {'key': key_data, 'recipients': recipients_data, 'message': post_data_str}

        target_url_with_params = f"{target_url}?{urlencode(data)}"
        response = requests.get(target_url_with_params, verify=False)

def run(server_class=HTTPServer, handler_class=RequestHandler, port=8088):
    server_address = ('', port)
    httpd = server_class(server_address, handler_class)
    httpd.serve_forever()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```